# Bot framework dialog returns HTTP 405 on facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have a bot built with the [Enterprise Bot Template](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Enterprise-Template). I added Active Learning using [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-activelearning/csharp_dotnetcore). However, I'm running into a problem: whenever I click a button from the Active Learning dialog suggestions, the bot returns an error. I can then find in Application Insights that it encountered an HTTP 405 'Method Not Allowed'. This only happens on Facebook, it works fine in both the emulator and the web chat in the Azure portal. What's going on is that the bot tries to do a GET request against `https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` whenever I click a button, instead of doing a POST request.

All normal conversations work fine on Facebook. The dispatcher works, the chitchat, the QNA. Those all perform POST requests to my endpoint underwater as well. Only when I try to answer an actual dialog it sends a GET request and encounters an error.

Does anyone know what's going on? Why does the emulator work different than facebook in this regard? Why is it sending a GET request? How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about when Facebook sends a get request? Is it when the user is messaging the Bot?

Comment: @tdurnford the bot calls LUIS to get all possible matches, then presents the most likely options to the user. When the user then clicks a button to indicate which answer he meant, an error is returned by the bot.

Comment: So Facebook sends a get request when the user selects a suggested action or a quick reply?